# TypeScript and type-safe array.reduce

Tags: typescript

I’m using the Array `reduce` function to create a keyed object representation of an array. I have a working solution already, but noticed there are multiple ways to ensure the output object is type-safe.

Given that I have the following interface and array:

```js
interface Meta {
  name: string;
  value: string;
}

const metaArr: Meta[] = [
  { name: 'a', value: 'hello' },
  { name: 'b', value: 'hi' }
];
```

Out of the following three solutions, are any of them generally preferred, or is there a better way to do this?

1. Use `Record` when declaring the `reduce` function:

```js
const metaObj = metaArr.reduce<Record<string, Meta>>((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr.name] = curr;
  return acc;
}, {});
```

2. Declare dynamic keys mapped to the `Meta` interface for the initial object:

```js
const metaObj = metaArr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr.name] = curr;
  return acc;
}, {} as { [key: string]: Meta });
```

3. Use `Record` to cast the initial object:

```js
const metaObj = metaArr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr.name] = curr;
  return acc;
}, {} as Record<string, Meta>);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd use the first approach you have. Because, using as is (at least in my opinion) a possible pitfall. As it "overrides" the type-system. Side note: if you still want to go with the as cast, you should use the Record<string, Meta> thingy. Anything else might fall at your feet sooner or later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this may be a trivial example there are some opinionated considerations to be discussed. Preferring one representation over the other is inherently subjective. Each solution functionally achieves the exact same result as any other, and the "testability" of each are also equivalent.

So based on your code, here are some things I may think about in order to help me with similar decisions:

- `reduce<Record<string, Meta>>` is one of the first things you see when reading the code and without having scroll a potentially large reduce projection, it is clear the shape it will produce.
- `{ [key: string]: Meta }` is generally not as readable as the first point type declarations using `Record<T, R>` and there's more to write to achieve the same goal
- `{} as Record<string, Meta>`: using `as` "assertions" is by no means a code smell, but referring to the first point again, readers of your code will need to look for the resultant type of the reduce by going to the bottom of the function

Usually when faced with these kinds of questions, all roads lead to the readability of your code. And while readability is also inherently a subjective pursuit, the more explicit and contained things are, generally, the easier it is to infer what a block of code is attempting to do.